# how to distinguish two different URL ID as a paramater

Tags: visualforce

I am calling one visualforce page from two different places in salesforce, one from Custom button and one from another Visualforce page . the way I am passing the information is through the ID parameter. one of them id is `apex/multiAttachment?mId=` and the other one is `apex/multiAttachment?jFk=`

I need to distinguish which one is coming in so I can run certain section of the quote

```
String button = ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('JFG');
String ap = ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('mId');
```

so pretty much I wanna say

```
if it contains JfG{
//do this}

if is mId{
do this}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any errors that we can help you with?

Comment: @AdrianLarson if the URL doesnt contain JFG, would it throw an error? what if the URL is coming from some where else and only has mId in it. Also I tried to get the content of that page and throws error ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('mId').getContentAsPDF();

Comment: @AdrianLarson this might be a bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as is, with the following warning:
A missing parameter will return null from `getParameters().get('mID')`;

So, you will want to use something like:

```
String mID = ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('mID');
String dfG = ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('dfG');

if(mID != null) {
    do the mID logic }

if(dfG != null) {
    do the dfG logic }
```

Comment: getParameters() returns a Map<String, String> so you can use the containsKey() method to check whether it exists first.

Comment: Agreed, that would be clearer.

Comment: Thank you @KenLynch just quick question "One of those Strings will be empty" depends where they come from, That wont throw me an error right?

Comment: Where the parameter doesn't exist, that parameter's string from the get will be null.

Comment: The null by itself won't be an error. The error is when you try to use the "null" variable, as bez showed above. You should make sure your string is not null at the beginning of your condition with "if(mId != null){...logic...}".  Using Nick's idea of contains(..) is also a good protection around your conditional logic. "if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().contains('mId') { ... logic ...}"